# Set CORS headers for fast-refresh in CRA

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, fast-refresh

```json
{
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
}
```

My React app is loaded across domain in development, and I have configured my React app to also load bundle chunks across domain using `__webpack_public_path__`.

For example:

Page on `https://test.local` -> embeds `https://host.docker.internal:3002/static/js/bundle.js` -> loads `https://host.docker.internal:3002/static/js/0.chunk.js`.

The issue is during hot-loading, the update JSON is also loaded from cross-domain resulting in a CORS error:

[image: Console showing CORS error]

As CRA doesn't allow configuration access to webpack-dev-server, I can't think of a way around this aside from disabling fast-refresh via the `FAST_REFRESH=false` env variable.

Does anyone have a better idea or solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your CORS issue and this is always facing when developers are working in different domain.

There are lots of way to pass CORS issue but I will tell you how to deal with CORS in react app.

**Manual Proxying**
If we need more control over how these cross-domain requests get made, we have another option, which is to create a file `src/setupProxy.js` that looks like this:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = app => {
  app.use(
    "/api",
    proxy({
      target: "http://localhost:4000",  // target server address and port
      changeOrigin: true
    })
  );
};
```

But we can go further, and use `http-proxy-middleware`'s options like pathRewrite to change the path of the request:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = app => {
  app.use(
    "/api",
    proxy({
      target: "http://localhost:4000",
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        "^/api": "/api/v1"
      }
    })
  );
};
```

If your web app needs to request data from a different domain, and you want your development environment to mimic a production configuration where frontend and backend are served from the same domain, make sure to take a look at the proxy and `src/setupProxy.js` options of Create React App. They'll make development of your app much easier!

I hope my experience will help you and others.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't quite what I'm looking for. `setupProxy.js` allows proxying unknown requests through the dev-server to another address. I am trying to allow x-domain requests to the hot-update bundles.

Comment: Another way to work around it is to directly add the require CORS headers to the dev server.

`
devServer:{
   ...
   headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET.POST.PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "X-Requested-With, content-type: Authorization"
     }
}

**Helpful Link**
[Webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-headers-)

}
`

Comment: I'm using CRA so do not have access to the underlying Webpack dev server, and I don't want to eject for this issue.